# Unable to get Hot Reload working with HotSwapAgent

Tags: java, tomcat, hotswap, dcevm, hotswapagent

Hi I am Using Trava Open JDK 8.
https://github.com/TravaOpenJDK/trava-jdk-8-dcevm

Got the tomcat to read hotswap-agent.properties.
Had set the the following properties.

```
extraClasspath=/Users/......./tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes
autoHotswap=true
autoHotswap.port=5005
LOGGER=debug
```

Got the following Debug Log messages when starting tomcat.

```
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@44c8afef

 patched with plugin classes from agent classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2.

HOTSWAP AGENT: 20:52:42.445 DEBUG (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginConfiguration) - Classloader contains 'hotswap-agent.properties' at location 'file:/Users/......./tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/hotswap-agent.properties'

HOTSWAP AGENT: 20:52:42.445 DEBUG (org.hotswap.agent.util.classloader.URLClassLoaderHelper) - Added extraClassPath URLs [file:/Users/......./tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/] to classLoader ParallelWebappClassLoader

  context: ROOT

  delegate: false
```

Compiled the classes and tried Copying .class files alone and also tried com/././x.class to the extraClassPath folder mentioned above. Hot Reload did not happen. Any pointers ?